# Can we add navigation bar with dropdown menu on single page website?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, single-page-application

Can we add **navigation** bar with **dropdown** menu on single page website?  if possible, how to handle navigation for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can.  For navigation try using [Bootstrap's Scrollspy plugin](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy)

All you have to do then is populate your navbar with `a` elements who's `href` corresponds to the content `div`'s `id`:

```
<a href="#my_div_id">My Div</a>

...

<div id="my_div_id">Content here</div>
```

Comment: Thanku.for help. Can you define what is the maximum length of navigation links on the single page website? Is it effectively effect website's loading?

Comment: The number of navigation items will be limited by usability long before any technical problems arise, so for all practical purposes there is no limit to the number of links on a page.  For a "normal" number of links, using the plugin shouldn't noticeably slow the page loading at all.